# Asynchronus Requests for writing into Dynamo db

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb

What are the issues while doing asynchronous requests for Dynamo DB ? Is it advisable to use when we are using a lot of write operations ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the AWS SDK in any number of languages, when you submit async requests it simply means the call to the AWS SDK will be non-blocking.  This is implemented entirely client side.  This also means it is the responsibility of your application code to make sure that the write request actually succeeded.

It is really more of a programming style choice and depending on your programming language of choice and framework that you are using.

Generally speaking using async requests could result in better throughput for applications making a large number of write requests to DynamoDB, but this could be accomplished using synchronous requests and multithreading.